# Magento Multi-Website Setup Question

Tags: multistore, stores, setup

Is it possible to have 2 different websites with the same products, categories, and currency; but different shipping methods and payments?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes.

You can add a product and make it visible across multiple websites (in the same install of magento, using multistore)

Payments and shipping methods can be set up by website (not store view, although you can change the description by store view)